# lapackのdgeqr関数の返り値の仕様がわからない

Tags: c++

c++でopenblasからlapackを使っています。
QR分解のためのルーチンとしてdgeqr関数があるのは調べたのですが、返り値の仕様が理解できていません。
目的としては、行列AをQR分解して、直行行列Qと上三角行列Rを得たいです。
どのように呼び出して、上記の2つの値を得ればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`dgeqr`を呼び出した後、`R`は（書き換えられた）`A`の中に含まれています。`Q`を得るには`dgemqr`を呼び出す必要があります。LAPACKはFortranのサブルーチンなので列優先であることに注意してください。以下はC++14での例です。

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

extern "C" {
void dgeqr_(const int &m, const int &n, double *a, const int &lda, double *t,
            const int &tsize, double *work, const int &lwork, int &info);
void dgemqr_(const char &side, const char &trans, const int &m, const int &n,
             const int &k, const double *a, const int &lda, const double *t,
             const int &tsize, double *c, const int &ldc, double *work,
             const int &lwork, int &info);
}

void print_matrix(int m, int n, double *a) {
  // column-major
  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      cout << a[i + j * m] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  // example
  const int m = 3; // # of rows
  const int n = 3; // # of columns
  array<double, (m * n)> a = {
      12,  6,   -4,  // 1st column
      -51, 167, 24,  // 2nd column
      4,   -68, -41, // 3rd column
  };

  // print A
  cout << "A =" << endl;
  print_matrix(m, n, a.data());

  // workspace query
  double t_query[5];
  double work_query[1];
  int info;

  dgeqr_(m, n, a.data(), m, t_query, -1, work_query, -1, info);
  assert(info == 0);

  int tsize = (int)t_query[0];
  int lwork = (int)work_query[0];

  // perform QR factorization
  vector<double> t(max(5, tsize));
  vector<double> work(max(1, lwork));

  dgeqr_(m, n, a.data(), m, t.data(), tsize, work.data(), lwork, info);
  assert(info == 0);

  // extract R
  const int rm = min(m, n);
  const int rn = n;
  array<double, (rm * rn)> r = {};
  for (int i = 0; i < rm; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rn; j++) {
      if (i <= j) {
        r[i + j * rm] = a[i + j * m];  // diagonal and above
      }
    }
  }

  // workspace query
  const int qm = m;
  const int qn = min(m, n);
  array<double, (qm * qn)> q = {};
  for (int i = 0; i < min(qm, qn); i++) {
    q[i + i * qm] = 1;  // (possibly truncated) identity matrix
  }
  dgemqr_('L', 'N', qm, qn, qn, a.data(), m, t.data(), tsize, q.data(), qm,
          work_query, -1, info);
  assert(info == 0);

  lwork = (int)work_query[0];

  // reconstruct Q
  work.reserve(max(1, lwork));

  dgemqr_('L', 'N', qm, qn, qn, a.data(), m, t.data(), tsize, q.data(), qm,
          work.data(), lwork, info);
  assert(info == 0);

  // print Q
  cout << "Q =" << endl;
  print_matrix(qm, qn, q.data());

  // print R
  cout << "R =" << endl;
  print_matrix(rm, rn, r.data());
}
```

結果：

```
A =
12 -51 4
6 167 -68
-4 24 -41
Q =
-0.857143 0.394286 0.331429
-0.428571 -0.902857 -0.0342857
0.285714 -0.171429 0.942857
R =
-14 -21 14
0 -175 70
0 0 -35
```